# Useless Plesk Error?

Tags: centos

I am trying to determine why Plesk on my server won't start and I have no idea where to even start (since my hosting company appears to not want to help me out).

Anyways, the error in my Plesk error_log is as follows:

2010-12-25 21:30:28: (log.c.75) server started
2010-12-25 21:30:28: (network.c.336) SSL: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0)
2010-12-25 21:30:28: (log.c.75) server started
2010-12-25 21:30:28: (network.c.336) SSL: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0)

It leads me to believe its a problem with the SSL on the server but I am not sure what to make of the error.

Can someone lead me in the right direction?

Thanks

Josh Pennington

Comment: Was your server previously working correctly?  Have you made any changes?  Did the hosting company?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lame answer but you can try to increase log level, or run plesk server manually with output to stdout/err with -ddd or -vvv

also you can google it:

http://forum.parallels.com/showthread.php?t=100608
http://kb.parallels.com/8338

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about which version this error was reported. But as per my knowledge this was a error in versions below 9.5

Root cause was with faulty sw-cp-server package. And the fix was there in a Parallels KB article. I would be glad to redirect users there:

http://kb.sp.parallels.com/en/8338